# Adding Game Center turn-based multiplayer to an existing bundle id

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm trying to add TBM to an app that already had a few versions released on the App Store (including game center leaderboards).

To get started, I first created a new test app on itunes connect and implemented all the basic methods I would need; everything was working smoothly.
I then proceeded to integrate the framework on my live app. It sort of works, but it has a few issues. The most obvious ones:

- receivedTurnEventForMatch never fires
- Game Center notifications are never received

Long story short: I went back to my test project, replaced the bundle id with the one from the live app, and this way it has exactly the same issues.
Of course, Game Center is enabled on this app and leaderboards are working as expected.

Any idea on what might be the issue? Is there any particular care to take when extending GC functionality to an existing app?

Comment: An update: the issue doesn't depend on the bundle id being released or not. I created a brand new app id and it has exactly the same issues.

Comment: Only the test bundle id I created weeks ago works flawlessly, all the other ones have common issues regardless of xcode or itunes connect settings. At this point I'm stuck, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you get any solution. i had same issues.

Comment: No there's no solution, but it's apparently an Apple issue related to the sandbox switch off occurred in October. See this thread for more info: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23938